# How can i add libz.1.2.3.dylib to iOS 9.1 in Xcode 7?

Tags: ios

when i wants add libz.1.2.3.dylib to project, but i can not found it, just found like libz.1.2.*.dytbd, how can i add this?

my environment Xcode 7, iOS 9.1.

please give me some help, many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your information from `Xcode 7` `libz.1.2.3.dylib` and all `.dylib` Framework change into `.tbd` Framework. And That's also not effect to old version Xcode version

Comment: @DiegoPeng please Can you upVote my answer

Comment: sorry, usually i forgot this.